# hive query with between in join working in llap but not in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Below range query with join working fine in llap, but not in Hiveserver2/Hive.CLI.

Please suggest how to work with range join query in Hive.

Hive version : 1.2.1.2.6

HDP version : 2.6.0.3

Query:

```
select * from datahub.cgs_tmp_gre gre
INNER JOIN datahub.cgs_tmp_cgsrxclm_ev_ba ba
ON gre.guar_key = ba.guar_key and gre.serviced_dte = ba.serviced_dte
AND gre.ts between ba.obsv_start_ts and ba.obsv_stop_ts
AND gre.ts between ba.obsv_start_ts and ba.obsv_stop_ts
AND gre.phcy_claim_id=2;
```

Below is the error thrown when we run it in hive CLI or hive server 2:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'obsv_stop_ts' (state=42000,code=40000)

Comment: do you get an error? if so, could you post it as well?

Comment: Thanks Vamsi for your quick response. I have updated the question with error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because you have the same `join` condition twice. `between` resolves to `>=` and `<=` and inequalities aren't supported in `join` conditions (before version 2.2.0). Move the condition to `where` clause and it should work.

```
select * --specify required columns rather than *
from datahub.cgs_tmp_gre gre
INNER JOIN datahub.cgs_tmp_cgsrxclm_ev_ba ba
ON gre.guar_key = ba.guar_key and gre.serviced_dte = ba.serviced_dte
WHERE gre.ts >= ba.obsv_start_ts and gre.ts <= ba.obsv_stop_ts --replaced between with >= and <=
AND gre.phcy_claim_id=2;
```

Comment: Getting similar error after using this query :
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 4:4 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'obsv_start_ts' (state=42000,code=10017)

Comment: @NSSaravanan .. moved the condition to `where` .. try it now.

Comment: Good suggestion, It will work for Inner join. I have query with 17+ table joined using both LEFT and INNER join. So WHERE will not work for LEFT join. Do you have any suggestion for let join?

Comment: @NSSaravanan .. please post a different question.